# Slack API - Number of messages sent by a user

Tags: slack, slack-api

i am trying to use the API to get the total number of messages posted by each user during a certain period. Ideally, I would be able to break the number of messages by the type of channel (public, private, direct messages.) Is this possible? I am looking through the API documentation but haven't found anything. I would be using it to create a script that would automatically generate weekly activity reports.

Thank you for any advice you can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special endpoint for this information as far as I know, but you can generate something similar yourself by looping though all channels and counting the message per user, e.g.

1. Get list of all channels with [conversations.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list)
2. Get history of each channel with [conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history)
3. Count messages per user

Of course your results would not include message from channels, that your bot has no access too (e.g. some private channels, direct message channels).

Comment: I just tried the conversations.list method and it does not return private conversations.

Comment: make sure to include `im ` in the `types`parameter to get those

Comment: And you will only see IMs from your own user, not from other users.